# JavaScript Canvas on draw vanishes

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas function which draws a square if I click on the canvas field and move the mouse, that works so far.

My Problem is that if I release the mouse and click at the canvas again the old drawn rectangle vanishes.

How do I make it possible that the old drawn does not get vanished.

My function:

```
function foo() {

    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    var canvasx = canvas.offsetLeft;
    var canvasy = canvas.offsetTop;
    var last_mousex = 0;
    var last_mousey = 0;
    var mousex = 0;
    var mousey = 0;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        if(checkboxSquare.checked) {
            last_mousex = parseInt(ev.clientX-canvasx);
            last_mousey = parseInt(ev.clientY-canvasy);
            context.strokeStyle = $('#selectColor').val();
            context.lineWidth = $('#selectWidth').val();
            tool.started = true;
        }
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started && checkboxSquare.checked) {
            mousex = parseInt(ev.clientX-canvasx);
            mousey = parseInt(ev.clientY-canvasy);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear canvas
            context.beginPath();
            var width = mousex-last_mousex;
            var height = mousey-last_mousey;
            context.rect(last_mousex,last_mousey,width,height);
            context.stroke();
        }
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started && checkboxSquare.checked) {
            tool.mousemove(ev);
            tool.started = false;
        }
    };
}
```

It Looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/kqW4X/

Comment: Probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old drawn rectangle vanishes on click because, you are clearing the entire canvas each time before drawing a rectangle.

The *easiest* workaround would be to save the entire canvas as an image on mouseup and draw that image before drawing each rectangle.

```js
var canvas;
var _foo = new foo();
canvas.onmousedown = _foo.mousedown;
canvas.onmousemove= _foo.mousemove;
canvas.onmouseup = _foo.mouseup;

function foo() {

 canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var checkboxSquare = $('#checkboxSquare')[0];
 var img = new Image();
 
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    var last_mousex = 0;
    var last_mousey = 0;
    var mousex = 0;
    var mousey = 0;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        if(checkboxSquare.checked) {
            last_mousex = ev.offsetX;
            last_mousey = ev.offsetY;
            context.strokeStyle = $('#selectColor').val();
            context.lineWidth = $('#selectWidth').val();
            tool.started = true;
        }
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started && checkboxSquare.checked) {
            mousex = ev.offsetX;
            mousey = ev.offsetY;
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear canvas
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // draw saved canvas (image)
   context.beginPath();
            var width = mousex-last_mousex;
            var height = mousey-last_mousey;
            context.rect(last_mousex,last_mousey,width,height);
            context.stroke();
        }
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started && checkboxSquare.checked) {
            tool.mousemove(ev);
   img.src = canvas.toDataURL(); // save canvas as image
            tool.started = false;
        }
    };
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: default;
  margin-top: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSquare">Square | Color
<select id="selectColor">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select> | Width
<select id="selectWidth">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi again do you know how to make the size of a pencil or rectangle appears depending to the width which the user took, so that the user can actually see the size on the mouse and not after drawing

Comment: @Micheasl umm.. maybe. but that's completely a different question. you should ask a new question with more details what you wanna achieve, rather than asking it on a comment :-)

Comment: I have an erase function which erases the canvas, but the old squares remain any idea how to erase them aswell?

Comment: I am basically runnning this function on button click http://kopy.io/C6Ftq it erases the canvas but if I add another square the old squares are shown as well

Answer (score 1):

Just create a background canvas same as the main canvas. When you drag out a new box, first draw the background canvas (with all the past boxes) on the main canvas then the current box being drawn. When you finish dragging the box, just daw it to the background canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const background = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.style.border="2px solid black";
canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
background.width = canvas.width = innerWidth - 24;
background.height = canvas.height = innerHeight - 24;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
background.ctx = background.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var currentBox;
const boxStyle = {
    fillStyle : "#4aF",
    strokeStyle : "black",
    lineWidth : 3,
    lineJoin : "round",
}
const mouse = { x : 0, y : 0,button : false, changed : false };
["mousemove","mousedown","mouseup"].forEach(en => document.addEventListener(en, mouseEvent));
function createBox(x,y,w,h,style){ return {x,y,w,h,style,draw : drawBox} }    
function drawBox(ctx){ 
    setStyle(ctx, this.style);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
    ctx.fill(); 
    ctx.stroke(); 
}
function setStyle(ctx, style){ Object.keys(style).forEach(key => ctx[key] = style[key]) }        
function mouseEvent(event) {
    mouse.x = event.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = event.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    if(event.type === "mousedown"){ mouse.button = true }
    else if(event.type === "mouseup"){ mouse.button = false }
    mouse.changed = true;
}
function mainLoop(){
    var b = currentBox; // alias for readability
    if(mouse.changed){
        if(mouse.button){
           if(!b){
               b = currentBox = createBox(mouse.x,mouse.y,0,0,boxStyle); 
           }else{
               b.w = mouse.x - b.x;
               b.h = mouse.y - b.y;
           }
        }else if(b){ 
           b.draw(background.ctx);
           b = currentBox = undefined;
        }
        if(b){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
            ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
            b.draw(ctx);
            canvas.style.cursor = "none";
        }else{
            canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
        }
        mouse.changed = false;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

#### Extra Note. Capture the mouse using the Document

When you create canvas drawing apps you should listen to the document mouse events rather than the canvas. When the mouse button is down the mouse is captured and will continue to send mouse events while the mouse is down, even if you have moved off the canvas, document, or event outside the browser window.

This means you can drag content of the canvas and not worry about losing the mouseup event.

#### Burn some time.

I have some time to burn so will extend the demo above to include selecting and moving existing boxes. Draw boxes as normal. Mouse over boxes will highlight them, click to select them. When selected can be dragged. Uses the same method background image to hold old boxes. But have added a box list to hold old boxes
A more extensive example

```js
   const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const background = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.style.border="2px solid black";
    canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
    background.width = canvas.width = innerWidth - 24;
    background.height = canvas.height = innerHeight - 24;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    background.ctx = background.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var currentBox;
    var selectedBox;
    var mouseOverBox;
    const styles = {
        box : {
            fillStyle : "#4aF",
            strokeStyle : "black",
            lineWidth : 3,
            lineJoin : "round",
        },
        highlight : {
            strokeStyle : "white",
            lineWidth : 1,
            lineJoin : "round",
            setLineDash : [[10,10]],                
        },
        selected : {
            strokeStyle : "red",
            lineWidth : 2,
            lineJoin : "round",
            setLineDash : [[5,5]],                
        },
    }    
    const boxes = {
        items : [],
        add(box){   // add a box and fix width and height to positive
          if(box.w < 0){
             box.x += box.w;
             box.w = -box.w;
          }
          if(box.h < 0){
             box.y += box.h;
             box.h = -box.h;
          }
          boxes.items.push(box) 
        },
        apply(name, ...args){
            for(var i = 0; i < boxes.items.length; i ++ ){ 
              boxes.items[i][name](...args);
            }
        },
    };
    
    const mouse = { x : 0, y : 0,button : false, changed : false };
    ["mousemove","mousedown","mouseup"].forEach(en => document.addEventListener(en, mouseEvent));
    const boxBehaviours = {
        draw(ctx, style = this.style){ 
            if(!this.hide){
              setStyle(ctx, style);
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.rect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
              if(style.fillStyle) { ctx.fill() }
              if(style.strokeStyle) {ctx.stroke() }
            }
        },
        isPointOver(x,y){
            var b = this;
            if(x >= b.x && x < b.x + b.w && y >= b.y && y < b.y + b.h){
                b.mouseOver = true;
                boxBehaviours.topMouseBox = b; 
            }else {
                b.mouseOver =false;
            }
        },
    }
    function createBox(x,y,w,h,style){ 
        return {x,y,w,h,style, ...boxBehaviours};
    }    
    function setStyle(ctx, style){ 
        Object.keys(style).forEach(key => {
            if(typeof ctx[key] === "function"){
                ctx[key](...style[key]);
            }else{
                ctx[key] = style[key];
            }
        })
    }
    function mouseEvent(event) {
        mouse.x = event.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
        mouse.y = event.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
        if(event.type === "mousedown"){ mouse.button = true }
        else if(event.type === "mouseup"){ mouse.button = false }
    }
    function redrawBackground(){
        background.ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
        boxes.apply("draw",background.ctx);    
    }
    function mainLoop(time){
        var b = currentBox; // alias for readability
        var mob = mouseOverBox; // alias for readability
        var sb = selectedBox; // alias for readability
        // first check mouse button. If button down could be
        // dragging a selected box or creating a new box
        if(mouse.button){
           if(sb){  // is selected box
              if(!mouse.drag){  // start the drag
                 mouse.drag = {x : mouse.x - sb.x, y : mouse.y - sb.y}
              }else{ // move the box                 
                 sb.x =  mouse.x- mouse.drag.x;
                 sb.y =  mouse.y- mouse.drag.y;
              }
           }else{ // else muse be create (or select click)
             if(!b){
                 b = currentBox = createBox(mouse.x,mouse.y,0,0,styles.box); 
             }else{
                 b.w = mouse.x - b.x;
                 b.h = mouse.y - b.y;
             }
           }
        }else if(b || sb){  // mouse up and there is a box 
           if(sb){ // if selected box
              if(mouse.drag){  // is dragging then drop it
                  mouse.drag = undefined;
                  sb.hide = false;
                  redrawBackground();
                  sb = selectedBox = undefined;
              }
           // is the mouse is down and has not moved over 2 pixels
           // and there is a mob (mouseOverBox) under it 
           // then dump the new box and select the mob box
           }else if(Math.abs(b.w) < 2 && Math.abs(b.h) < 2 && mob){
              sb = selectedBox = mob;
              mob = mouseOverBox =  undefined;
              b = currentBox =  undefined;
              sb.hide = true;
              redrawBackground();           
           }else{
               // just a normal box add it to box array
               // draw it and remove it from currentBox
               boxes.add(b);
               b.draw(background.ctx);
               b = currentBox = undefined;
           }
        }
        // clear andf draw background
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
        ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
        if(b){ // is there a current box then draw that
            b.draw(ctx);
            canvas.style.cursor = "none";
        } else {  // no current box so 
            // find any boxes under the mouse
            boxBehaviours.topMouseBox = null;
            boxes.apply("isPointOver",mouse.x, mouse.y);        
            // is there a selected box (sb)
            if(sb){ // yes selected box then draw it
              ctx.save(); 
              styles.selected.lineDashOffset  = time / 25;
              sb.hide = false;
              sb.draw(ctx,styles.selected);
              sb.hide = true;
              ctx.restore();
              canvas.style.cursor = "move";
          // no selected box sp then just high light the box under the
          // mouse and assign it to mouseOverBox (mob);
          }else if(boxBehaviours.topMouseBox){
                mob = mouseOverBox = boxBehaviours.topMouseBox;
                ctx.save(); 
                styles.highlight.lineDashOffset  = time / 20;
                mob.draw(ctx, styles.highlight);
                ctx.restore();
                canvas.style.cursor = "pointer";
            }else{
                canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

Comment: Hi thanks I will check this, one question do I Need to create the canvas with JavaScript or is that just a better practice?

Comment: @Micheasl I use my own editor which uses a different type of markup so I just add the DOM stuff by hand in javascript. In page or via code each has its pros and cons. Best practice is to use what you feel comfortable using.

Comment: @Micheasl I forgot to say. The important part and best practice is not to use the mouse events to do any type of rendering. It is slow and inefficient, and gets worse and worse as you add functionality to the mouse events. Use the main loop and only with requestAnimationFrame to do any regular rendering. This will ensure the best performance as rendering is synced with the display hardware

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `foo()` function is being called for every frame, either through `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`. If my assumption is right, the reason why your previously drawn square disappears is because you are only storing the x and y coordinates of one rectangle, and every time you click on the canvas again, it gets overwritten by the new values for the new rectangle.

To solve your problem, you should store the x and y coordinates as well as the dimensions of the square on mouseup. These coordinates can be stored in an array.

```
var squares = [];

this.mouseup = function (ev) {
    // other code
    var square = { 
        x: last_mousex,
        y: last_mousey,
        width: mousex - last_mousex,
        height: mousey - last_mousey
    };
    squares.push(square);
};
```

Now every time you draw the square, draw the squares stored in the `squares` array first.

```
this.mousemove = function (ev) {
    if (tool.started && checkboxSquare.checked) {
        // other code
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear canvas

        // draw each square in the squares array after clearning the canvas
        squares.forEach(function(square) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(square.x, square.y, square.width, square.height);
        });

        context.beginPath();
        var width = mousex - last_mousex;
        var height = mousey - last_mousey;
        context.rect(last_mousex, last_mousey, width, height);
        context.stroke();
    }
};
```

You'll see some code repetitions in drawing the squares, it's a good opportunity to abstract it into a separate function.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I tried your Suggestion but it did not work, same result + no error in Chrome dev console

Comment: @Micheasl did you draw the squares in your `squares` array? i'll update the post to show where to place it :)

Comment: Hmm I tried this but it does not work do you have a working jsfiddle for better comparism

Answer (score 0):

```js
var point = [];
var clicks = 0;

var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
// Creating a tmp canvas
var tmp_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var tmp_ctx = tmp_canvas.getContext('2d');
tmp_canvas.id = 'tmp_canvas';
tmp_canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
tmp_canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

sketch.appendChild(tmp_canvas);
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.id = 'paint';
canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

sketch.appendChild(canvas);

tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown, false);
tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove, false);
tmp_canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup, false);

function mousemove(e) {
  if (clicks == 1) {
    x = e.layerX - this.offsetLeft;
    y = e.layerY - this.offsetTop;
    showRect(x, y);
  }
}

function showRect(x, y) {
  tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear canvas
  tmp_ctx.beginPath();
  var width = x - point[0].x;
  var height = y - point[0].y;
  tmp_ctx.rect(point[0].x, point[0].y, width, height);
  tmp_ctx.stroke();

}

function mousedown(e) {
  x = e.layerX - this.offsetLeft;
  y = e.layerY - this.offsetTop;
  point.push({
    x,
    y
  });
  clicks++;

};

function mouseup() {
  context.drawImage(tmp_canvas, 0, 0);
  clicks = 0;
  point.length = 0;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
}

#sketch {
  border: 10px solid gray;
  height: 100% ;
  position: relative;
}

#tmp_canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sketch">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try to do in temporary canvas and redraw all in main.

jsfiddle:-https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/v0m06faz/